# the width problem of 3 divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, width, overflow

I want to put 3 parallel divs in html. div middle should be the width of `960px` and center of the page, div left and div right will be both site of the div middle,the page min-width will be `1024px`, when the browser's width is more than `1024px`,div left and div right maybe width `(100%-960px)/2` the overflow-x is hidden. When the browser's width is equal and less than 1024, div left and div right maybe width `32px` (`(1024-960)/2=32px`), overflow-x is scroll(the page width show `1024px`. I use this code,but it can not adjust the width unless refresh the page. How to do dynamic adjustment width and overflow-x?
Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<style> 
*{padding:0;margin:0;} 
#box {min-width:1024px; _width:960px;} 
#left {width:32px;float:left;background-color:blue;} 
#middle {width:960px;float:left;background-color:red;} 
#right {width:32px;float:left;background-color:green;} 
</style> 
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
var width = document.body.clientWidth; 

if(width>1024){ 
$('#box').css({ 
width:width + 'px' 
});     
$('#left').css({ 
width:(width-1024)/2+32 + 'px' 
}); 
$('#right').css({ 
width:(width-1024)/2+32 + 'px' 
}); 
} 

}); 
</script> 
<div id="box"> 
<div id="left">1</div> 
<div id="middle">2</div> 
<div id="right">3</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: This would seem to be a JavaScript problem, rather than CSS. And specifically, jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var width = document.body.clientWidth;
  windowResize(width);
  $(window).resize(function() { 
    windowResize(width);   
  });
});

function windowResize(width) {
  if(width>1024){ 
    $('#box').css({ 
      width:width + 'px' 
    });     
    $('#left').css({ 
      width:(width-1024)/2+32 + 'px' 
    }); 
    $('#right').css({ 
      width:(width-1024)/2+32 + 'px' 
    }); 
  } 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by binding some javascript code to the resize event:

http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: I have no idea of resize event. I will read the article. or if some one can modify my code for I can know clearly.